# Flutter Windows Desktop Support

Tags: windows, flutter, desktop

Im currently working on a MacBook developing a Flutter app for Android and IOS, and both are running fine on simulators from my Mac. I use VS Code.

Now I want to add desktop support to it (specifically Windows) but I just read that in order to do that, it has to be built on Windows.

Does that mean I’ll have to create a new project on a Windows PC and manually copy all of my files to it and have 2 different set of codes?

Answer (score 1):

Just move your project to a device running Windows OS and build the file output for Windows OS.

```sh
flutter config --enable-windows-desktop
```

```sh
flutter build windows
```

[more info](https://docs.flutter.dev/desktop)

Comment: But then, if I want to keep on running it on iOS will I have to keep on moving it back and forth or is there another alternative?

Comment: for tasting, u need to use CI/CD services but for export the final file, u need to move to another OS, or u can by windows/mac VPS or some CI/CD services also have the ability to give you output for different platforms.

Comment: Can you please me an example on testing for windows on VS. Code on a mac?

Comment: To compile a desktop app, you must build the app on the targeted platform: build a Windows app on Windows, a macOS app on macOS, and a Linux app on Linux.[link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59735) maybe there will be changes in the future

Answer (score 0):

You need a Windows environment to enable windows support.

```
on Windows, you can dev: android + web + windows
on macOS, you can dev: android + web + iOS + macOS
on Linux, you can dev: anroid + web + linux
```

You can share the same project among these environments. Once you enable a certain platform, it will create a separate folder for it. So if you enable multiple, your project will simply have multiple folders in its root, such as "ios", "web", "macos", etc.

For windows, you also need to install VS2022, for macOS you need XCODE, for Linux you also need some tools (the installation is made into a script, so just run that).

[For more info, head over to flutter.dev](https://docs.flutter.dev/desktop).